# Look for gaps in time stamps

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following time stamps in a file that goes on for maybe 24 hours or slightly more:

```
2014-11-11-04.01.05.000000
2014-11-11-04.03.33.000000
2014-11-11-04.06.02.000000
2014-11-11-04.08.31.000000
```

The gaps between each time stamp should be less than 5 minutes.  How can I put a simple bash shell script together to parse through the file and tell me if there are gaps greater than 5 minutes?  The simplest way I see would be to subtract the next line with the previous line.  But I'm not really good with bash shell script.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This uses GNU `date` to interpret the time.  The code below reads from a file named `file` and, looping over each line, checks to see if a time gap of more than 300 seconds exists:

```
while read newline
do
    new=$(date -d "$(echo "$newline" | sed -E 's/-([0-9][0-9])\.([0-9][0-9])\./ \1:\2:/')" '+%s')
    if [ "$old" ] && (( $new - $old > 300))
    then
        printf "%4i seconds gap before %s" "$((new - old))" "$newline"
    fi
    old=$new
done <file
```

#### Example

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
2014-11-11-04.01.05.000000
2014-11-11-04.03.33.000000
2014-11-11-04.08.31.000000
2014-11-11-04.13.32.000000
2014-11-11-05.13.33.000000
```

The above script finds the two gaps that exceed 5 minutes:

```
 301 seconds gap before 2014-11-11-04.13.32.000000
3601 seconds gap before 2014-11-11-05.13.33.000000
```

Observe that this can detect gaps as small as 5 minutes and 1 second.  It also detects the 1-hour gap even though the minutes didn't change.

#### How it works

To understand the time format in all its potential complexity, the GNU `date` utility is used to convert time to seconds-since-epoch.  This is done simply as:

```
$ date -d '2014-11-11 04:01:05.000000' '+%s'
1415707265
```

My `date` (newer versions may differ) does not support the exact format of our input:

```
$ date -d '2014-11-11-04.01.05.000000' '+%s'
date: invalid date `2014-11-11-04.01.05.000000'
```

However, we can use `sed` to make the format look like the one above which worked:

```
$ date -d "$(echo "$newline" | sed -E 's/-([0-9][0-9])\.([0-9][0-9])\./ \1:\2:/')" '+%s'
1416384000
```

Next, it is a matter of getting those seconds into a shell variable.  To do that, command substitution is used:

```
new=$(date -d "$(echo "$newline" | sed -E 's/-([0-9][0-9])\.([0-9][0-9])\./ \1:\2:/')" '+%s')
```

With the most recent time in the variable `new`, we can see if more than 5 minutes (300 seconds) has elapsed since the last time (stored in the variable `old`) and, if so, print out a message:

```
if [ "$old" ] && (( $new - $old > 300))
then
    printf "%4i seconds gap before %s\n" "$((new - old))" "$newline"
fi
```

The first test above, `[ "$old" ]` makes sure that the variable `old` has been defined.  It will always be defined except for the first line that we read in.  Hence, the effect of the test `[ "$old" ]` is to skip that first line.

The second test is `(( $new - $old > 300))`.  This simply determines if more than 300 seconds has elapsed since the previous line.

#### What to do if your `sed` does not support `-E`

For GNU `sed`, `-E` means extended regex format.  On Mac OSX, `-r` would be used in its place.  If you are on an old linux system that doesn't support `-E`, we can try using basic regular expression syntax.  Try:

```
$ echo 2014-11-11-04.01.05.000000 | sed  's/-\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)\./ \1:\2:/'
2014-11-11 04:01:05.000000
```

And:

```
$ date -d "$(echo 2014-11-11-04.01.05.000000 | sed  's/-\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)\./ \1:\2:/')" '+%s'
1415707265
```

As you can see, the difference between basic and extended regex is which characters have to be escaped.

If that works, then use:

```
while read newline
do
    new=$(date -d "$(echo "$newline" | sed  's/-\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)\./ \1:\2:/')" '+%s')
    if [ "$old" ] && (( $new - $old > 300))
    then
        printf "%4i seconds gap before %s" "$((new - old))" "$newline"
    fi
    old=$new
done <file
```

Comment: Thanks you for the fast response. My ancient Rhel 5.6 box is complaining about no -E option for sed, and when I tried the -e option, I got the following:

$ echo 2014-11-17-08.55.42.000000 | sed -e 's/-([0-9][0-9])\.([0-9][0-9])\./ \1:\2:/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 40: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @rcboosted OK.  I just added a solution that does not use `-E`.  Give it a try.

Comment: @rcboosted By the way, `-E` is extended regular expression which is quite different from `-e` which (optionally) precedes a sed command.

Comment: Thank you very much John and all those who helped.  The regular expression sub worked. Looks like the static value was used in the latest script instead of $newline in the original script.  I modified it and tested on a file I have and it worked perfectly as expected.

Comment: @rcboosted Glad it is working.  And, you are right about the static date.   Answer is now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU awk, which has builtin time functions:

```
gawk '
  {
    split($1, a, /[-.]/)
    t = mktime(a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3] " " a[4] " " a[5] " " a[6])
  }
  NR > 1 && t - prev > 300 {print NR, $0}
  {prev = t}
' <<END
2014-11-11-04.01.05.000000
2014-11-11-04.03.33.000000
2014-11-11-04.06.02.000000
2014-11-11-04.08.31.000000 
2014-11-11-04.15.12.0
END
```

```
5 2014-11-11-04.15.12.0
```